# Failed to open terminal on code-server on alpine linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, alpine-linux

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error relocating /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/build/Release/pty.node: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeEPKNS_9CFunctionE: symbol not found).

My user settings value:

```
{
    "go.useLanguageServer": true
}
```

My terminal logs showed these errors:

```
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.587Z] info  code-server 3.8.0 c4610f7829701aadb045d450013b84491c30580d
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.590Z] info  Using user-data-dir ~/.local/share/code-server
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.695Z] info  Using config file ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.695Z] info  HTTP server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080 
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.696Z] info    - Authentication is enabled
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.696Z] info      - Using password from ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
[2021-01-14T08:11:39.696Z] info    - Not serving HTTPS 
Error: Error relocating /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeEPKNS_9CFunctionE: symbol not found
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at bindings (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/spdlog/index.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at t.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:17:960)
    at e.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:13:941)
    at o (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:189)
    at Object.errorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:313)
    at e.triggerErrorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:306)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:10
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:18:342)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13) {
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'spdlog',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous3===' ]
}
Error: Error relocating /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeEPKNS_9CFunctionE: symbol not found
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at bindings (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/spdlog/index.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at t.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:17:960)
    at e.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:13:941)
    at o (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:189)
    at Object.errorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:313)
    at e.triggerErrorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:306)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:10
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:18:342)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13) {
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'spdlog',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous3===' ]
}
[2021-01-14T08:11:52.407Z] error exthost console {"arguments":"[\"Error: Error relocating /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeEPKNS_9CFunctionE: symbol not found\\n    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)\\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)\\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)\\n    at Function.t._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:1065:961)\\n    at Function.i._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:1035:665)\\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)\\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)\\n    at bindings (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)\\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/spdlog/index.js:3:35)\\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)\\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)\\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)\\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)\\n    at Function.t._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:1065:961)\\n    at Function.i._load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:1035:665)\\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)\\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)\\n    at t.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:17:960)\\n    at e.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:13:941)\\n    at o (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:189)\\n    at Object.errorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:313)\\n    at e.triggerErrorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:306)\\n    at /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:10\\n    at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:18:342)\\n    at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:115:16)\\n    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13)\"]","token":"cc585d5e-035d-4875-9d18-cdd3e2a29183"} 
innerError Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/pty.node'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/lib/unixTerminal.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/lib/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/bootstrap-amd.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/server/fork.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/lib/unixTerminal.js:31:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/lib/index.js:14:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at t.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:17:960)
    at e.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:13:941)
    at o (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:189)
    at Object.errorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:31:313)
    at e.triggerErrorback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:306)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:14:10
    at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:18:342)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:261:13) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/lib/unixTerminal.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/node_modules/node-pty/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/bootstrap-amd.js',
    '/usr/lib/node_modules/code-server/lib/vscode/out/vs/server/fork.js'
  ]
}
PROTOCOL CORRUPTION, LAST SAW MSG 0 AND HAVE NOW RECEIVED MSG 38
```

Comment: I am using alpine linux 3.12.3, `Linux fh-forest-thinkpad-e550 5.4.84-0-lts #1-Alpine SMP Wed, 16 Dec 2020 11:01:26 UTC x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I am using Alpine Linux 3.14.3 and code-server version 3.2.0 and this issue still persists

Answer (score 1):

I solved this entirely by accident, by being accommodating to external developers. The error is misleading, implying the nonexistence of needed libraries, but it assumes bash is installed.

Either install bash or add a terminal profile for ash in Settings, then use it as your terminal shell.